# Windows Phone - XNA game - Back button

Tags: xna, windows-phone

I have some problem with my back button. In my game I have two screens. One with title (menu) and second with the game. When I use once back button i pause game and back to title screen. When i use it again I need to kill the app process. How can i do that? Down below i show u how I use back button. I try use 2 gestures, but when I declared them nothing go right.

That's how i declared gesture in `Initialize()`:

`TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag`

First I declared

```
bool IsPlayingGame = true;
int endGame= 0;
```

Then in function `Update`:

```
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if (!IsPlayingGame) this.Exit();
}


if (isTitleScreenShown)
{
    UpdateGameScreen();
}
else if (isGameSceenShown)
{
    UpdateTitleScreen();

    // TODO: Add your update logic here
    /* MY FUNCTIONS */

    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        if (endGame == 5) base.Exit();
    }
}
base.Update(gameTime);
```

In Visual studio, it works. I thought great, but on Nokia phone it doesn't. Why? Any help?

Comment: Maybe the phone back button code isn't the same as gamepad's back button code. Try looking for other options of using your button.

Comment: I just repair this. I forgot to use function earlier. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GamePage.xaml.cs there should be a method `protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)`

This method is triggered when you touch the 'back' button on your device.